# Using SpEL for non-string (xs:boolean) attributes in Spring XML

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-el

Consider the following Spring Security related piece of Spring XML context:

```
<authentication-manager erase-credentials="true">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user disabled="${auth.admin.enabled}" name="${auth.admin.user}"
              password="*****"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

This snippet was supposed to keep admin user enabled based on the property value. But XML validation is not passing for this snippet, because `disabled` attribute of `user` tag is declared with type `xs:boolean`, which means SpEL syntax is not allowed there.

Is there a way to achieve my purpose (user, enabled by a property) without refusing from Spring XML context?

Comment: The easiest way is to use Java configuration instead of XML. You don't have to use it for all Spring related configuration, just for Spring Security. Or just for the authentication manager.

Comment: If you really insist to use XML, you could try to disable schema validation. I don't recommend it, because it would be hard to find errors in your XML.

Answer (score 0):

No; the schema would need to be changed to accept a union of `xsd:string` and `xsd:boolean`. You might want to open an Improvement JIRA issue.